# Can Discord Bot send a message on a channel to everyone

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm coding a discord Bot with the discord.js library on a nodeJs server.
Here is my question: is that possible when an event occure (like someone sending a message) that the bot answers to members of a role, or to everyone. The message.reply("my reply") method only answer to the author of the message as I use it for now...

Comment: You can find all the members of an role  and make a foreach to all members in that role

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending private message to a group of user (Discord.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56263758/1092820)

Comment: I understand how to do that but what I don't get is how to send the message to the role member through the reply method.

Comment: on a foreach you will have the member promise and you can make member.reply

Comment: You're asking an [XY question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/405359). Why bother using `msg.reply` here if it's not going to be of any use to you? [The accepted answer at the proposed duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56264694/1092820) does exactly what you need, you just need to put it in a `client.on("message", msg => {...});` call, and get the guild from `message.guild` or whatever.

Comment: You teach me something ( I didn't know what is a XY Question), I saw the previous answer you posted and it half answer to my question. I now know how to target users with a private message but not how to send a message on a channel, mentionning to every member of the role.

Comment: `message.channel.send(member+"Your message")`

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that [`message.reply()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reply) is a very limited method: it *always* mentions the author of the message, and you can't override that.

You need to use a more generic method, [`channel.send()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send), and construct the mention yourself. `.reply()` is just a shortcut for a frequently used form of it, but you need something custom.

Presumably, you want it to happen in the same channel as the message, so you need `message.channel.send("Whatever content you want")`.

Now, to add a role, you need to decide how to pick one. Is it fixed? Then you could [hard-code a role mention by role ID](https://discordjs.guide/miscellaneous/parsing-mention-arguments.html#how-discord-mentions-work): `<@&134362454976102401>` (of course, it needs to be the role ID you require).

If you want to find a role, for example by name, you need to do that via searching through the guild in question. You can access it though `message.guild`, but be warned that it will be undefined for DMs.

Then you can do something like

```
const role = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name === "NameYouWant");
message.channel.send(`${role} something something`);
```

because Role objects become mentions when converted to strings.

Comment: Thanks Xan, this perfectly answers to my problem. I have already retrieved the role through the guild.I think I would have hardly find by myself that roles convertion turns them into strings so the last part of code is of great use.

Comment: @Xan please see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58541634/11253551)