# chrome.notifications.update does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have some progress notifications and I simply want it to be updated, but it goest from 0% to 1%, and then staies there, at 1%.

here my code:

```
var notifId = uuidv4();
    var i = 0;
    var notifOptions = {
        type: 'progress',
        iconUrl: 'img/GS icon.png',
        title: 'test',
        progress: i,
        requireInteraction: true,
        message: 'Downloading...',
        buttons: [{
            title: 'Abort download'
        }]
    };
    chrome.notifications.create(notifId, notifOptions);
    setInterval(function () {
            chrome.notifications.update(notifId, {
                progress: ++i % 100
            }, function () {});
        },
        1000);
```

where

```
//create a unique id for eatch notification
function uuidv4() {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0,
            v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });
}
```

what' the problem? why it stucks on 1% ?

Comment: Your code is correct and it works for me so the problem must be somewhere else in the real extension that isn't shown here. Is your real interval 5000 or bigger and you're using a persistent:false background script? If so, you'll have to keep the script alive, there are some tricks.

Comment: @wOxxOm, I'm using `"persistent": false` should I switch to `true`?

Comment: See [Persistent background page on demand or an event page that doesn't unload?](//stackoverflow.com/a/58577052)

Comment: @wOxxOm how is it working for you? my code is insode function taht I invoke it on page load...

Comment: I think it should be simple so I don't know what's the problem.