# How do I find all members with a specific role on 'ready'? Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm aware that this question has been asked before, but I'm yet to find a solid answer for the newest version of Discord.JS. I'd like to find all of the members in the guild hostGuild that have the role 'xyz'.

```
client.on('ready', () => {
    const hostGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('822234110369595443');
    //get users with role 'xyz'
    }
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list all Members with a Role In Discord.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897574/how-do-i-list-all-members-with-a-role-in-discord-js)

Comment: That is an old version of Discord.JS

Comment: It should still work in v12. Edit: Nevermind you're right...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `.members.cache`? It would look like this:

```js
const membersWithRole = hostGuild.members.cache.filter(m => m.roles.cache.has('roleid'));
```

---

EDIT: It doesn't seem to work, because the members and roles are not cached. You will need to use async/await here:

```js
const allMembers = await hostGuild.members.fetch();
const membersWithRole = allMembers.filter(m => m.roles.cache.has('roleid'));
```