# how to store all the data of only the members who have a specific role with discordjs v12

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, discord, discord.js

I have a discord js related problem....I actually want to get all the members in the guild with one specific role `yeet1` in a single array.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
if(msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('+info mod')){
    const Members = msg.guild.members.cache.filter(mem => mem.roles.cache.find(role => role.id == '822075908231659550')).map(member => member.user.tag).join('\n');
    console.log(Members);
    msg.channel.send(`Users with yeet1: ${Members}`);
}
```

But it returns an empty array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I list all Members with a Role In Discord.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897574/how-do-i-list-all-members-with-a-role-in-discord-js)

Answer (score 0):

This question is already answered here [How do I list all Members with a Role In Discord.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897574/how-do-i-list-all-members-with-a-role-in-discord-js/48912041)

If you still need help try this

```js
let membersWithRole = message.guild.members.filter(member => { 
        return member.roles.cache.find("name", roleName);
    }).map(member => {
        // Do whatever you want
    })
```

Here's a way more easy way (Might need intents)

```js
message.guild.roles.get('415665311828803584').members.map(m=>m.user.tag)
```

Comment: Do you have intents ?

Comment: @alubhau I think you should take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica/64559391#64559391).

Comment: @Tyler2P wow that worked!!!! thank you very much dude :3 really appreciate it!! I actually didnt know about intents but now I know!!! thanks to you. Thanks again man