# How to create dump command without presence intents

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am creating a `dump command`, here is my code:

```js
let role = message.mentions.roles.first() || message.guild.roles.cache.get(args[1]);

let oop = message.guild.members.cache.filter((member) => {
    return member.roles.cache.get(role.id);
  })
  .map((member) => {
    return member.user.tag;
  });

message.channel.send(`${oop.join("\n")}`);
```

**I can't turn it on since my bot is verified and Discord won't approve my request because they won't grant intents just for 1 tiny command**

I also know that you can fetch members using

```
guild.members.fetch()
```

But `guild.members.fetch()`  Takes way longer than `guild.members.cache` So you will need to use `await` and/or `.then()`

I just don't know how to implement that to my code.

I am not sure if there is a way to do it, but if there is let me know :D.

Comment: what is a dump command exactly?

Comment: @Radnerus when I do !dump <role ID> It will show all the people who has the role.

Comment: Discord is now enforcing to enable the intent. So you cant do this, without enabling the intents.

Answer (score 0):

#### Basically

The is a shorter / easier way to get all `members` of a specific `role`:

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Name of your role').members.map(m => m.user.tag);
```

Alternatively, you can also use the `ID` of a `role` to retrieve it:

```js
message.guild.roles.cache.get('your role Id').members.map(m => m.user.tag);
```

---

Both will return an `array` of `user tags`. Afterwards you can `.join()` this array to whatever format you want / need, e.g.:

```
const roleMemberList = message.guild.roles.cache.get('12345678910').members.map(m => m.user.tag).join('\n');
```

The output would look like this:

> ```
> "Member1
>  Member2
>  Member3"
> ```

#### But...

According to the [docs](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#gateway-intents) you are forced to enable the [privileged intents](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents) in order to get users from `cache`. If Discord doesn't whitelist your bot, you might want to consider other [use cases](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/360040720412#what-is-considered-an-acceptable-use-case) for the `intents`

So I guess you'll have to bite the bullet and use

```
guild.members.fetch()
```

until you get on the whitelist

---

#### Reference

- [Discord is now enforcing privileged intents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64559391/13685706)
- [How do I list all Members with a Role In Discord.Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897574/how-do-i-list-all-members-with-a-role-in-discord-js)
- [Roles and Permissions](https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/understanding/roles.md) (This is really worth a look)