# How to list all members with a specific role with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots, roles

I try to make a simple bot that just lists all members that have a specific role.

I went through most of the similar questions I could find, but their answers seem outdated. So I tried this but end up with the result 'undefined', although the role exists.

```
const discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const client = new discord.Client(
    { intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, 
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS
    ] });


const prefix ="!";
const MemberID = "912852591023628371";

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Connected to the bot');

  

});

client.on('messageCreate', msg => {
    if (msg.content === 'hi') {
        msg.reply('Hi to you too!');
    }
  
});

client.on('messageCreate', async message => {
    if (message.content === prefix + 'list') {
        let list = client.guilds.cache.get(MemberID);
        console.log(list);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
    message.guild.roles.cache.get('Your role id here').members.map(m=>m.user.tag);
```

This will return an array of all users with the role.

Comment: Thanks! I am actually pretty confused by the discord.js docs... tried to wrap it like this, but still gives "undefined". ```client.on('messageCreate', async message => {

    let getAllMemberWithRoles = async () =>  {
        let list = await client.guilds.cache.get(MemberID);
        console.log(list);
    }
    if (message.content === prefix + 'list') {
        getAllMemberWithRoles();

    }
}
);```

Comment: Hah, looks like my answer about promises was absolute rubbish! The discord js guide says to use a method instead. Updating answer. If that doesn't work, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897574/how-do-i-list-all-members-with-a-role-in-discord-js

Comment: Thanks, but I tried these. Seems as if they are outdated? Throws error: "get is not a function"

Comment: Hmm. After doing a little testing on my own, `message.guild.roles.cache.get('role-id').members.map(m=>m.user.tag);` works for me. I got the same error as you , but adding .cache fixed it.