# List all users with a specific role with DiscordJS

Tags: javascript, collections, discord, discord.js

I already checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70994110/how-to-list-all-members-with-a-specific-role-with-discord-js?noredirect=1&lq=1) but this unfortunately doesn't seem to help in my case. I am trying to list all members in a server that have the role with id 'roleID'. I get that role like so:

```
const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(guildID);
const role = await guild.roles.fetch(roleID);
```

However, whenever I try to print the roles.member property, I get an empty collection, and trying to map it out returns an empty array

```
console.log(role.members);
>>Collection(0) [Map] {}
console.log(role.members.map(users => users.user.tag));
>>[]
```

And I am absolutely stumped as to why. I know the ID is definitely correct since printing out the role lists all the correct information, and I used roleID to successfully assign the role to a few users in the server.

And yes, I triple checked, there are definitely users in the server that have the role

Comment: What intents have you enabled?

Comment: I have Flags.GUILDS

Comment: must be another error, since i tried this code and it worked perfectly fine.

Comment: have u tried adding         FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, might help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [None of my discord.js guildmember events are emitting, my user caches are basically empty, and my functions are timing out?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64559390/none-of-my-discord-js-guildmember-events-are-emitting-my-user-caches-are-basica)

Comment: As Ramy mentioned, you'll need to add `GUILD_MEMBERS` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weirdly enough what seems to fix this issue on my side is not adding the `GuildMembers` intent, but adding the `GuildPresences` intent.

I don't know why that happens since this intent is unrelated, but you could try it as a solution to your problem.

You also need to make sure that you enabled this intent at https://discord.com/developers/applications -> Bot -> Enable Presence Intent

Image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sYiK.png